# How to use big file only to build the container without adding it?

Tags: docker

I have a big tar/executable (over 30GB) I `COPY/ADD` it but this is used only for the installation. Once the application is installed I don't need it anymore.

How can I do? I am trying to use it but:

- Everytime I run a build, it takes minutes to define the build context.
- I'd like to share this image, if I create a tar with `docker save`, Is the final version or each layer included in it?

I found some solutions that said I can use `RUN wget tar ... && rm tar` but I don't want to create webserver for that.

Why isn't possible to mount a volume during build process?! It would be very useful.

Comment: It seems Docker doesn't want to implement this feature. I let open this post for some hours just to be sure.

Comment: Does this big tar/executables changes frequently in your case ?

Comment: Not at all, it's a fixed iso, that's why I'd like to avoid loading it every time I build the image. They should add a cache for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Docker's multi-stage builds. This mechanism allows you to drop intermediate artifacts and therefore achieve a lightweight image.

Example:

```
FROM alpine:latest as build
# copy large file
# build

FROM alpine:latest as output
# copy necessary files built in the previous stage
COPY --from=build app /app
```

Anything built in the `build` stage will not be included in the final image, unless you explicitly `COPY` them.

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: I believe he is facing issue to reduce build context size rather than image size.

Comment: Thanks, actually both, but for now it's more to reduce the context. How to avoid the `COPY`? I am gonna accept this answer since it seems there is no solution, we have to copy the image or use a wget. Why not trying `wget` with a localhost web server that is accessible from container... the copy should stay fast as `COPY` and without the context loading at each build.

Comment: This fixed the image's size but not the time it takes to send context to daemon.

Answer (score 2):

This is solvable using 2 different context.

Please follow these steps as mentioned below.
**Objective is to create a**

1. docker image that will have you large-build file.
2. docker image that will have you real codebase/executables.

For this you have to create 2 folders (Build & CodeBase) as follow.

  `Application<br/>
  |---> BUILD <br/>
  |======|--->Large-File<br/>
  |======|--->Dockerfile<br/>
  |--->CodeBase<br/>
  |======|--->SRC+Other stuff<br/>
  |======|--->Dockerfile<br/>`

Build & Codebase both folders will have individual Dockerfile and arrange files accordingly.

Dockerfile(Build)

```
FROM **Base-Image** 
COPY Large-File /tmp/Large-File
```

Build this and tag it with some name like (base-build-app-image)

```
#>cd Application <==Application root folder as mentioned above==>
#>docker build -t base-build-app-image BUILD <==path of your build-folder==>
```

Dockerfile(Codebase)

```
FROM base-build-app-image 
RUN *****
CMD *****
RUN rm -f **/tmp/Large-File**
RUN rm -f **Remove installation files that is not required**
ENTRYPOINT *****
```

Build this-code-base and base-build-app-image is already in your local docker-repository and your large iso file is not in the current-buid-context

```
#>cd Application <==Application root folder as mentioned above==>
#>docker build CodeBase <==path of your code-base==>
```

This time since the context size is only your code base 
and since this doesn't include that **Large file** - it will definitely reduce your build time.

You can also take an advance of using docker-compose to do both operations together so you will not have to execute 2 separate commands.

If you need help on preparing this docker-compose file then do let me know in comments.
If anything is not clear then leave a comment or come over chat to fix this issue.

Comment: I ended up by doing what you explained! But I `COPY` file from the first image to by second image using `multi-stage building`. I mixed both answers. Once everything works perfectly, I am gonna learn `docker-compose`. Thanks! not sure I can accept two answers...

Comment: Does this helped you to reduce build time ?

Comment: For production, not sure it'll be faster than one image using multi-stages. For debugging and development, it's much faster. 1st `base-build-image`: load big files, do whatever immutable. 2nd image `FROM base-build-image` I can try what I want. In that case once the 1st image is built, I don't need to wait for the long loading context each time I want to try a build.